# Pre installed Qt designer 4.6.2 no option for c++ creation

Tags: qt

At my work we have a pre installed version of qt designer 4.6.2,
The problem is that pre installed version 
Seems to only create the ui file,
I dont have an option to create new c++ file or  class 
How can i add this option to the qt desginer ???
Thanks dart

Comment: Do you mean, you are also using the ancient Qt 4.6.2? Or is that just the version number of Qt Designer? If the latter, then which version of Qt are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old *Qt Designer* is just for editing .ui files. It is not related to creating Qt code (C++, QML, Python...). The *Qt Creator*, a completely separate application, is a full-fledged IDE, which includes the old Qt Designer as a (small) part of it, and these parts are fully compatible AFAIK (the .ui file format has not changed).

So you need to install Qt Creator to have something which helps you create Qt C++ classes etc. I'm not sure, but I don't think they've explicitly dropped support for old Qt, so you can just try by installing the latest Qt Creator, then adding your Qt version to it manually. If you have trouble with this, you may want to ask a new question, but the gist of it is, add the Qt version by pointing Qt Creator to *qmake* binary of the Qt version you want to use, and then create a kit which uses that Qt version.